# I am new to Javascript, Can anyone provide instructions to run RAPTOR repository on any GTFS set

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, shortest-path, raptor

REPO: https://github.com/planarnetwork/raptor

I am trying to run Depart after query. Output for any GTFS will suffice. The query given as such is giving error related to assync function. I have modified the query to :

```
 var fs = require("fs")
const {loadGTFS, JourneyFactory, RaptorAlgorithmFactory, DepartAfterQuery} = require("raptor-journey-planner");
async function run(){
    var stream = fs.createReadStream('C:/Users/Admin/raptor/gtfs.zip')
const [trips, transfers, interchange, calendars] = await loadGTFS(stream);
const raptor = RaptorAlgorithmFactory.create(trips, transfers, interchange, calendars);
const resultsFactory = new JourneyFactory();
const query = new DepartAfterQuery(raptor, resultsFactory);
const journeys = query.plan('590', '593', new Date(), 9 * 60 * 60);}
run().catch(e => console.error(e));
```

590 and 593 are stops in my set. But this is also not working

Any help will be much appreciated.